# Comparing the difference between two dates in the US Date Standard of mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, compare

I need your help,

How can one compare the difference between two given dates while using the US date standard of mm/dd/yyyy?

A few examples below:

```
11/20/2014 minus 11/25/2014 = -5

11/25/2014 minus 11/25/2014 = 0

11/27/2014 minus 11/25/2014 = 2
```

Comment: You should separate this into two tasks: 1) parsing the value from a string into a more appropriate format (e.g. `Date`); 2) comparing the two values produced by the parse step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date1 = new Date("11/20/2014");
var date2 = new Date("11/25/2014");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

try this

Comment: Be careful around DST. For example, date1 = new Date("11/2/2014"), date2 = new Date("11/3/2014"); This will produce a diffDays of 2 when it should really be 1... May want to use Math.round

Comment: @ashkufaraz how do you calculate months difference